# how can i implement this logic add(1)(2)(1).. upto (n)?

Tags: javascript, syntax, logic

I know this question is already answered with limited capability but I want it with n number of time with n arguments?

```
function add(x) {
    return function(y) {
        if (typeof y !== 'undefined') {
            x = x + y;
            return arguments.callee;
        } else {
            return x;
        }
    };
}
add(1)(2)(3)(); //6
add(1)(1)(1)(1)(1)(1)(); //6
```

problem is this works only when I add extra empty brackets ()
it doesn't work if do this `add(1)(2)(3)`

[reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272902/make-this-syntax-possible-var-a-add23-5)

Comment: You should make your question clear

Comment: @AndréPena the question is clear, perhaps you are simply not experienced enough in this style of javascript programming to understand it.

Comment: I think it's clear. He wants to curry a function unlimited times without having to execute the last function, getting the value right away. It is not possible, those things can't coexist. But, you can abuse `toString` or `valueOf`.

Comment: @elclanrs javascript can perform the `toString` method automatically in cases where an object is treated like a string, so it is possible, it just comes with a few caveats in the fact that it is an object that can be read as a string. (such as typeof equalling 'function', and other minor strangeness issues)

Comment: That's what I meant by "abuse".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
function add(x) {
    var fn = function(y) {
        x = x + y;
        return arguments.callee;
    };

    fn.toString = function(){  return x; };

    return fn;
}
```

Comment: +1 but this will not work if it is used in `console.log`

Comment: It is worth mentioning that `arguments.callee` shouldn't be used anymore, prefer a named function.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works exactly like you asked:

```
function add(a)
{
    var c=a,b=function(d){c+=d;return arguments.callee;};
    b.toString=function(){return c;}return b;
}
```

Do note that some operations will detect the result given as a function, but any functions that require a string or integer will see the proper value.

Answer (score -2):

Try sending your numbers as an array and changing your function code to reflect these changes.

Note: Code untested.

```
function add(x) {
   var result = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < x.length;i++){
   result+=x[i];
   }
   return result;
}

add(new Array(1,2,3));
```

Comment: The whole point here was to enable use of a special syntax, an array is not even needed if you just want to add arbitrary numbers in a function.