# Can someone explain me the flow of this JavaScript function? (Closure concept)

Tags: javascript, closures, currying

I'm reading "[Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/)". Chapter 3 introduces "[Closure](http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html#h_hOd+yVxaku)" concept and gives you a couple of examples. One of these is next one:

```
function multiplier(factor) {
    return function(number) {
        return number * factor;
    };
}

var twice = multiplier(2);
console.log(twice(5));
// → 10
```

I think I understood the concept. If first I execute `console.log(twice)`, since variable `number` is undefined, what I get is `[Function]`. What I don't understand is how `twice(5)` works. Why local variable `number` is initialized with value `5`?

Also, why if I execute `console.log(multiplier(2,5))` I don't get 10 as a result?

Thanks.

Comment: @Sidenote: Thanks!

Comment: It's a [curried function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272902/make-this-syntax-possible-var-a-add23-5)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because `multiplier` returns a function, so `twice` is equal to the returned function, NOT the `multiplier` function.

However, when `multiplier` is called the `factor` variable is passed and used within the returned function.

So to make it easier to understand, consider that `twice` is basically:

```
var twice = function(number) {
    return number * 2;
};
```

Where `factor` has been replaced by the value you passed in when calling `multiplier(2)`.

---

> I think I understood the concept. If first I execute `console.log(twice)`, since variable number is undefined, what I get is `[Function]`.

When you use `console.log(twice)` you are not actually calling the function `twice`, you are simply logging the value of it. So the output of `[Function]` is not because `number` is undefined, it is because you are outputting the actual function rather than the result of it.

---

> Also, why if I execute `console.log(multiplier(2,5))` I don't get 10 as a result?

Here you are calling the `multiplier` by providing 2 arguments, though you have only defined the function to accept one parameter (`factor`). In javascript, this won't cause an error, but you will just get the first value mapped in `factor` (`factor = 2`).

Note: There are ways to still access all the supplied arguments even if you don't have parameters defined for them ([here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13145228/838807))

Something that would be possible to get a result of `10` which might be of interest is to use the following code:

```
var result = multiplier(2)(5); // result = 10
```

Comment: Ok. Now I see it. And also I understand why multiplier(2,5) can't return 10. Thanks mate!

Comment: `factor` isn't passed to the anonymous function. It is accessible within the function, because it is a free variable and the anonymous function is a closure. This distinction is important, because free variables are stored on the heap, not the stack.

Comment: @LUH3417: I am saying the factor variable is passed when the `multiplier` function is called. I am not stating it is passed to the anonymous function. All I say is that it is *used* by the  returned function (anonymous). I think your comment will suffice for anybody who interprets my statement in the way you have

Answer (score 2):

multiplier is a function which returns anonymous function which accepts an argument(number)

```
var twice = multiplier(2);
```

Basically is :-

```
 var twice = function(number) {
        return number * 2;
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

If you execute

```
console.log(multiplier(2,5))
```

you call the function giving two parameters, whereas

```
function multiplier(factor) {}
```

only takes one parameter.