# How can I Make this syntax possible: var a = (5).plus(3).minus(6); //2

Tags: javascript

I know it is a wired question but I want to make this syntax to work in javascript:

```
var a = (5).plus(3).minus(6); //2
```

Inspired from: http://dmitry.baranovskiy.com/post/31797647

I have checked the [Answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272902/how-can-i-make-var-a-add23-5-work) but not getting any idea for dot(`.`) in the syntax.

Comment: `.` is property access, so you could patch `Number.prototype` to add these methods.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: thanks jonrsharp.. got it

Comment: There are other ways see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270127/can-a-1-a-2-a-3-ever-evaluate-to-true/51510208#51510208

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@jonrsharpe's proposal works:

```js
Number.prototype.plus = function(b) {
  return this + b;
}

Number.prototype.minus = function(b) {
  return this - b;
}

var a = (5).plus(3).minus(6); // 2

console.log(a);
```